# I'm checking in middleware if a user is logged in then he needs no header if user is not logged in and in api call he needs to add header token

Tags: laravel, middleware, custom-authentication

I'm checking in the middleware if a user is logged in. If so, then he doesn't need a header. If a user is not logged in and in an API call, he needs to add a header token. I'm facing an issue in (Auth::check()). It is not working fine

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::check()) {
        $token = $request->header('APP_KEY');
        $from = intval(time() / 3600 - 1);
        $to = intval(time() / 3600);
        $condition1 = md5('ABCD'.$from);
        $condition2 = md5('ABCD'.$to);

        if ($token == null) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 
                'App key not Found or user is not Login '], 401);
        } else if ($token == $condition1 || $token == $condition2) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 
                "App Key Not Matched".$condition1], 401);
        }
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: I want to check first if user is logged in then no further token is required

Comment: And your question is... ?

Comment: how can I do this in  middleware that if user is logged in than no token required?

Comment: Now it is clear what your question is. You say that `Auth::check()` is not working fine. Can you elaborate on that one?

Comment: As you can see I'm using condition !auth::check. works fine if user is not logged in but results are same if condition goes wrong, like if user is logged in, condition must call else function. instead of calling else, it runs as no user even user is logged in.

Comment: Okay. How do you know that the user is logged in when this fails to go to the else? What function call or what operation ensures that to you?

Comment: Auth::user() I'm checking by this check if user is logged in or not. also adding condition to it if the user is logged in it must go to else statement, otherwise should run if statement.

Comment: or do you have any idea to check if user is logged in ? and then use the answer for the if else condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the token in the cookie when user logged In successfully:

```
    // user login
    public function login(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'User not found',
            ], 404);
        }
        if (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Password is incorrect',
            ], 404);
        }
        $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->plainTextToken;

        $cookie = cookie('token', $token, 60 * 24 * 30);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User logged in successfully',
        ])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```

After that you have to go this file and add the following codes in handle method.
`app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php`

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {

        if ($token = $request->cookie('token')) {
            $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token);
        }

        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        return $next($request);
    }
```

In this way when you consume login API in your SPA the token will be stored in the browser's cookie (httpOnly) and then you can consume other API which is protected routes with no token in headers (It means you don't have to pass token in the header in any request after login).

And to remove token from both server and browsers's cookie then you can use this below code in logout method.

```
// user logout
    public function logout(Request $request) {
        $request->user()->tokens()->delete();
        $cookie = Cookie::forget('token');

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User logged out successfully',
        ])->withCookie($cookie);
    }
```